# Do I have any obligations if I upload an egg to the CheeseShop?

Tags: python, egg, pypi

Suppose I'd like to upload some eggs on the Cheese Shop. Do I have any obligation? Am I required to provide a license? Am I required to provide tests? Will I have any obligations to the users of this egg ( if any ) ?

I haven't really released anything as open source 'till now, and I'd like to know the process.

Comment: I think you just won the greatest question title. Ever.

Comment: i thought this was spam to start with O.o then i opened the thread..

Comment: I find it funny that Thomas Owens' comment has more upvotes than the question has upvotes AND answers. With a sidenote that I contributed one of the upvotes to said comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You have an obligation to register the package with a useful description. Nothing is more frustrating than finding a Package that *may* be good, but you don't know, because there is no description.

   Typical example of Lazy developer: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/0.9.1

   Better: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/itty/0.6.0

   Fantastic (even a changelog!): http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jarn.mkrelease/2.0b2
2. On CheeseShop you can also choose to just register the package, but not upload the code. Instead you can provide your own downloading URL. *DO NOT DO THAT!* That means that your software gets unavailable when cheeseshop is down *or* when your server is down. That means that if you want to install a system that uses your software, the chances that it will fail because a server is down somewhere doubles. And with a big system, when you have five different servers involved... Always upload the package to the CheeseShop as well as registering it!
3. You also have the obligation not to remove the egg (except under exceptional circumstances) as people who starts to depend on a specific version of your software will fail if you remove that version.

   If you don't want to support the software anymore, upload a new version, with a big fat "THIS IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED SOFTWARE" or something, on top of the description.

   And don't upload development versions, like "0.1dev-r73183".
4. And although you may not have an "obligation" to License your software, you kinda have to, or the uploading gets pointless. If you are unsure, go with GPL.

That's it as far as I'm concerned. Sorry about the ranting. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

See [CheeseShopTutorial](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) and [Writing the Setup Script](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to license the code. Despite what some people may think, the authors of content actually need to grant the license on their own. The Cheese Shop can't grant a license to other people to use the content until you've granted it as the copyright owner.

Comment: You don't grant the CheeseShop as a copyright owner. The sentence doesn't even make sense.